# SharePoint "Shared with Us" for External Users and External Users List

Tags: sharepoint-online, folder, site, external-users, external-sharing

I'm working on setting up a SharePoint site for my organization.

Here are parameters:

- We are an organization with a lot of different committees, which have an average of 10 members per committee.
- I have separated these committees into different folders within the SharePoint site, that way they don’t see materials of committees they are not a part of.
- Within these committee folders are folders with meeting materials for the committee members
  o   Example: October 2023 Committee Folder
- There are variations of these meeting folders depending on whether or not the person has a conflict of interest
  o   Example: Jane gets her ability to see the October 2023 Committee Folder because she has a conflict of interest
  o   Instead she sees a “Jane October 2023 Committee Folder” with the pages she cannot see removed. This file would then be unavailable to the rest of the committee members because it is not necessary to see them.
- This is we are handling permissions on an individual basis, instead of via groups, because we would end up with a high volume of groups.
- I’m open to using many different site settings, whether it be document center, team center, etc.
- This is the browser version.
  The issue I am having are the following in regards to SharePoint websites:
  SharePoint Access List:
- Is there a way to see a list of all external users within a SharePoint Site?
- If so, could we click on this list to see what has been shared with a user?
  o   Example: I click on this list and click on Jane
  o   I am then greeted with a list or report of everything she has access to.
- Does this feature exist? And how do I access it?
  “Shared with Us” for External Users:
- Users with Microsoft Accounts have access to “Shared with Us”
- This shows everything that has been shared with them
- When inviting non-Microsoft Account users to SharePoint Sites or Folders, how do I make it so they can see the “Shared with Us”?
- Or is there another work around that lets them see everything shared with them?
- What I’m essentially looking for is like Google Drive’s “Shared with me” but for external users.

Any answers, questions, suggestions, or even alternatives would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**SharePoint Access List:**
SharePoint doesn’t show a list of all external users.
You can see what’s shared externally from the Site Usage Report.

**"Shared with Us" for External Users:**
"Shared with Us" is available for users with Microsoft Accounts.
Non-Microsoft Account users can access resources with a temporary passcode.

**Google Drive’s "Shared with me" for external users:** Google Drive lets you share files with external users who don’t have Google Accounts. "Shared with me" shows files shared with you.